# PHP array filter by pre text from value

Tags: php, arrays, filtering

I have an array like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => country-indonesia
    [1] => country-myanmar
    [2] => access-is_airport
    [3] => heritage-is_seagypsy
)
```

From that array I want to make separate array only for [country] ,[access], [heritage]

So for that I have to check array value by text before '-'. I am not sure how to do it. so i can't apply code here. I just have the array in PHP

Comment: make an explosion by `explode("-", $val)` within a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A modified answer, if you want to get the specific types only.

```
<?php

$arr = [
  'country-indonesia',
  'country-myanmar',
  'access-is_airport',
  'heritage-is_seagypsy',
];

$new_array = [];
$types = ['country', 'heritage', 'access'];

foreach ($arr as $element) {
  $fac = explode('-', $element);
  foreach ($types as $type) {
    if ($fac[0] === $type) {
      $new_array[$type][] = $fac[1];
    }
  }
}

$country = $new_array['country'];
$access = $new_array['access'];
$heritage = $new_array['heritage'];


var_dump($new_array);
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple and easy solution in 3 lines of code using `array_walk`

```
<?php

$arr = [
    'country-indonesia',
    'country-myanmar',
    'access-is_airport',
    'heritage-is_seagypsy',
];

$new_array = [];
array_walk($arr, function($item) use (&$new_array){
    //if(false === strpos($item, '-')) return;
    list($key,$value) = explode('-', $item, 2);
    $new_array[$key][] = $value;
});


print_r($new_array);
```

Gives this output:

```
Array
(
    [country] => Array
        (
            [0] => indonesia
            [1] => myanmar
        )

    [access] => Array
        (
            [0] => is_airport
        )

    [heritage] => Array
        (
            [0] => is_seagypsy
        )

)
```

If you don't want empty and duplicate entries:

```
<?php

$arr = [
    'country-indonesia',
    'country-myanmar',
    'access-is_airport',
    'heritage-is_seagypsy',
];

$new_array = [];
array_walk($arr, function($item) use (&$new_array){
    if(false === strpos($item, '-')) return;
    list($key,$value) = explode('-', $item, 2);
    if(empty($value) || array_key_exists($key, $new_array) && in_array($value, $new_array[$key])) return;
    $new_array[$key][] = $value;
});


print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by using `explode` and `in_array` functions

```
 <?php
   $arr = ["country-indonesia","country-myanmar","access-is_airport","heritage-is_seagypsy"];
  $newArr = array();
   foreach($arr as $k=> $val){
      $valArr = explode("-", $val);
        if(!in_array($valArr[0], $newArr)){
           $newArr[] = $valArr[0];
        }
   }

   print_r($newArr);

  ?>
```

[live demo](https://eval.in/1053624)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May be i can't explain well. I got an array from ur code with pre value. I want to set array like this $country= array([0]=>indonesia [1] => thailand)

Comment: @Lemon : then I recommend Kerkouch answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need PHP's `strpos()` function.
Just loop through every element of the array and try something like:

```
if( strpos($array[$i], "heritage") != false )
{
    // Found heritage, do something with it
}
```

(Rough example written from my cellphone while feeding baby, may have typos but it's the basics of what you need)

Read further here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 0):

```
//first lets set a variable equal to our array for ease in working with i.e
// also create a new empty array to hold our filtered values 
$countryArray = array();
$accessArray = array();
$heritageArray = array();

$oldArray = Array(country-indonesia, country-myanmar, access-is_airport, heritage-is_seagypsy);

//Next loop through our array i.e

for($x = 0; $x < count($oldArray); $x++){
// now filter through the array contents
$currentValue = $oldArray[$x];
// check whether the current index has any of the strings in it  [country] ,[access], [heritage] using the method : strpos()

if(strpos($currentValue,'country')){
//if this particular value contains the keyword push it into our new country array //using the array_push() function.
array_push($countryArray,$currentValue);
}elseif(strpos($currentValue,'access')){
  // else check for the access string in our current value
  // once it's found the current value will be pushed to the $accessArray
array_push($accessArray,$currentValue);
}elseif(strpos($currentValue,'heritage')){
 // check for the last string value i.e access. If found this too should be pushed to //the new heritage array i.e
array_push($heritageArray,$currentValue);
}else{
// do nothing
}
}
```

//I believe that should work: cheers hope